# MySQL - Views w/ User-Defined Functions with Parameters From View Fields

Tags: mysql, sql, function, view

I'm making a scheduling database in MYSQL. I have a View that takes info from a list of leave requests (vacation, holiday, etc.) and displays it with the date.
I'm receiving an Error 1292: Incorrect date value when attempting to view the view. I know this error is typically when dates are improperly formatted, but all of the data is properly formatted (yyyy-mm-dd). I'm really stuck up on this and I can't seem to find any literature to amend the issue.

Here is the view

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `db`.`complete` AS
    SELECT 
        `db`.`datetable`.`Date` AS `D`,
        `db`.`mdcodes`.`Physician` AS `MD`,
        SCHEDULER(`db`.`datetable`.`Date`,
         db`.`mdcodes`.`Physician`) AS `Status`
    FROM
        (`db`.`mdcodes`
        JOIN `db`.`datetable`)
```

And here is the function

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `Scheduler`(MD VARCHAR(40), requestedDate Date) RETURNS varchar(40) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN
    DECLARE workTime VARCHAR(40);

    if !(isNull((SELECT LeaveType from LeaveSchedule where Dates=requestedDate AND Physician = MD)))
        THEN SET workTime = (SELECT LeaveType from LeaveSchedule where Dates=requestedDate AND Physician = MD);
    elseif (((SELECT weekOfMonth from clinics where Physician = MD)) = "A") 
        THEN SET workTime = (SELECT ClinicTimes from clinics where Physician = MD AND `Day` = DayOfWeek(requestedDate));

    END IF;
    RETURN workTime;
    END
```

The goal here is to sort of self propagate with the view fields, so the function would display accordingly to the date and physician in the same row in the view. Any help here would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I changed the name of one of the columns, and changed all the references to that column, and am receiving an Error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

As requested, here are some of the data inputs:

```
      Datetable (date datatype)           MDCodes (varchar(20) datatype)       
       |Date|                                     |Physician|
     2016-07-01                                    Doc1
     2016-07-02                                    Doc2
```

The tables used in the function are not an issue, the function works perfectly when used on its own.

Comment: Maybe you can show how you inserted the value of the date?

Comment: @keronconk I've updated the question in my edit